# Best ways to avoid getting hit by cars?

Tags: safety, traffic

When riding through city traffic, what are the best ways to increase the chance you are seen, given a bit of space, and are not touched by any vehicles?

Comment: Motorcycle escort?

Comment: Short & Simple:  
1) Drive bicycle roads (avoid highways, rural area roads) 
2) Assume drivers are idiots 
3) Don't listen to music 
4) Don't drink and drive!

Comment: @nerijusgood: Bicycleways are often quite dangerous where they cross/merge with normal roads.

Comment: @nerijusgood *engage smile mode* 1) Some cyclists live in rural areas, so they cannot be avoided. 2) Most cyclists are also drivers. 3) ... while cycling. 4) ... perhaps that's about alcohol. I get thirsty if I don't drink. :-)

Comment: Avoid rural roads? I seek them out. They're generally the best, safest cycling roads available and I think that applies worldwide.

Comment: I am reminded of a situation I encountered in Wisconsin about 20 years ago.  Was touring self-contained and entered a small town, following a state road.  Turned to go down Main Street and discovered that it was torn up, with only a narrow gravel path in each direction for 2-3 blocks.  Traffic was fairly heavy for such a small town.  After assessing my options, I simply dropped to my granny, moved into the center of the path, and continued at about 5 mph, letting the cars behind wait.  No one honked, no one seemed irritated, as they could see that this was my only real option.

Comment: The only time I was hit as a cyclist, it was by another cyclist.

Comment: @nerijusgood: I think it's funny that people say "car drivers are idiots" when they drive bicycles, and the very same people say "bicyclists are idiots" when they are driving cars. The same holds true for hikers, mountain bikers, dog walkers. Everyone is fighting everyone, even though everyone is everyone. And at any time, everyone is right. It's only a temporary state.

Answer (score 54):

As cyclists, we are vulnerable to any collision. A collision with a truck, bus, car, bicycle, pram, skateboard, rollerblader, pedestrian, dog, or even a domestic cat, will almost always cause a problem, if not an injury.

Vehicle drivers are just people like us, except that they are in a comfortable safe box, maybe with crying kids in the back, and a have just dropped an ice-cream on their lap. You cannot *expect* them to be looking out for you all the time.

So it's up to us to take 100% responsibility for our own safety. It doesn't help us if we were 100% in the right, but are 100% dead.

So ...

- Choose where you ride. Avoid high speed and congested roads. Statistics show that the probability of a collision rises rapidly after the speed difference between two road users exceeds 20 kph (12 mph). So choose paths without vehicle traffic, or roads with lower speed traffic. See [How does the risk of a cyclist colliding with a vehicle vary with the speed difference?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31585/how-does-the-risk-of-a-cyclist-colliding-with-a-vehicle-vary-with-the-speed-diff)
- D'oh! I originally left out **Ride where other people ride, or ride with a buddy.** Drivers are much more likely to notice multiple riders. And when there is more than one of you it's not so easy to justify squeezing past. Finally, those drivers who might be tempted to drive dangerously close are intimidated by the you having a witness.
- Avoid turns in the middle of congested intersections. If you feel in danger, then ride at the side of the road across the intersection, wait for the lights to change, then continue on the crossroad. In my town this is called a square turn, in other places it's called a hook turn.
- Keep reasonably close to the curb, about half a meter (yard) to one meter out. You need to ride in a straight line so that the vehicle drivers can predict your path, so ride where the road surface is at least adequate. In light traffic, move toward the curb a little as the vehicle approaches and then resume your position after the vehicle passes. In heavier traffic, just maintain your path. Some cyclists like to have a mirror to know what's happening behind them.
- Traffic behaviour can vary in different parts of the world, so take your local traffic conditions into consideration. In my town, the inner city traffic is congested but used to seeing cyclists. So if there is no bike lane, cyclists are generally able to mix with the traffic fairly safely *when the bikes are moving faster than the cars*.
- Wear brightly colored clothing. In some parts of the world, black is fashionable. Avoid it. One advantage of a lot of so-called Lycra is that most of it is brightly colored. Some people wear hi-visibility industrial safety tops.
- *Always* ride with lights turned on. If legal, then set them to flash mode. Choose lights that flash more than once per second. Slow flashing lights can be missed as drivers shift their attention quickly. Some places (Germany?) forbid flashing bike lights.
- And stay alert. *Listen* for traffic. *Don't* rely on them seeing you.
- In some situations, you need to take a whole lane, so that the drivers behind don't drive too close by trying to squeeze past when there is not enough room. You should only do this when the traffic is moving at a similar speed to you.
- And as mentioned by mjsqu in comments, keep away from parked cars to avoid doors.

Comment: IDon't ride too close to parked cars

Comment: „Always ride with lights turned on. If legal, then set them to flash mode.“
Flashing lights are annoying and make it harder to judge distance. I only use that mode on my secondary headlight when its battery is running low. Get a proper, street legal headlight (e.g. Philips SafeRide 80 when battery powered is required) and mount it properly.

Comment: @Michael What is legal varies from place to place, and AFAIK the research varies re distance judgement of each light. What is undisputed is that a flashing light gets noticed way before a constant light. Everybody has to do what *they* think is best though.

Comment: @Andy: Anyways, a flashing light is useless if you depend on it to see. Which is probably why proper headlights don’t have a flashing mode in the first place. I have two small “backup” lights which I occasionally use in flashing mode in addition to the proper head- and taillights.

Comment: Correct. We're talking about being seen.

Comment: "Statistics show that the probability of a collision rises rapidly after the speed difference between two road users exceeds 20 kph (12 mph)..." - Do you have the source for this info?

Comment: Personally, I find bright flashing front lights *very* annoying.  Being seen is essential but it's not the whole story.

Comment: @ebrohman Not to hand; I'll see if I can dig it out. I first learned about this 30+ years ago, when probationary drivers were required to drive slower than others. Because of the speed differences, they were at higher than normal risk of collisions.

Comment: One thing I've always heard is to make eye contact to make sure they see you.  Last weekend I was hit by a woman in an SUV despite that.  She looked at me as I was approaching, then looked away right as I went in front of her.  She then accelerated into the back of my bike while she was trying to do a right turn on red...

Comment: @Brian it's good to see you're still with us. She only had to remember you were there for 3 seconds; any injuries?

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by talking about lobbying efforts, as per Stephan Matthiesen's below. While _avoiding_ that one bad intersection or stretch of road is a good start, getting it _fixed_ means that if you do need to use it (when you're in a hurry) you can, and other less safety concious cyclists will be safer too. Lately a lot of cities are a lot more receptive to bike infrastructure than in the past, so I think this bears mentioning.

Comment: No injuries.  Luckily it was wet out, so it just spun me part way around and I stayed on the bike and upright.  No real damage to the bike either.  I only had to re-true the rear wheel so it wouldn't rub on the brakes.

Comment: @ebrohman I added a reference after a quick dig around. I'll add more as I find it.

Comment: Motorists' respect (and their visibility) for cyclists increases dramatically when you wear a **safety vest**. It reminds them, *oh right, this guy dies if I hit them*.

Comment: @ebrohman It may be useful if your comment became a question in it's own right. I'll wait a day to see if you ask it :-)

Comment: “D'oh! I originally left out Ride where other people ride, or ride with a buddy. Drivers are much more likely to notice multiple riders.” In my experience group rides tend to be more dangerous and can often lead to accidents without any car involvement at all. Groups are also harder to overtake, which annoys car drivers and tempts them into dangerous overtaking manouvers.

Comment: @Michael I didn't mention groups. Just ride where others do, or ride with a buddy. The OP doesn't mention groups either. The point is that other riders have worked out the better places for riding.

Comment: @Michael We like to have enthusiastic new users here; we're all enthusiastic about cycling. Many topics related to cycling are largely a matter of opinion, so the general behaviour here is to put our own point of view in our own answers, rather than engage in long comment discussions. For example, I liked most of your answer and voted it up, without comment on the rest. It's up to other people to read our answers and make their own minds up. On a topic like this, no single answer is the best for everyone. So having multiple answers expressing different view points is healthy.

Comment: Also: **don't** ride on zebra crossings and assume that the drivers will give you priority as they would to a pedestrian. I hate it when bike riders do it as it's confusing. Step off the bike and walk along when you cross those.

Comment: Brightly coloured clothing is the most important passive behaviour. Go for really bright, especially neon. And at night, or dusk as well, reflective surfaces. If your clothes are not reflective, get a diagonal shoulder band at least. And those reflectors on your wheels so you can be seen from the side.

Comment: You failed to mention chickens.  I once hit a chicken, and though it was a fair thump, it did not cause a crash.  (For me that is -- unsure of the chicken.)

Comment: @Daniel Lol! Come to think of it, wild ducks and black swans are a danger here also. Ducks because they are so unpredictable, swans because they seem to think they own whatever land they're on, refuse to move, are so big, and they *bite*.

Comment: you should add: check your local laws. In Spain it is mandatory to take the entire line.

Answer (score 27):

There are tips here: [Car Bike Collisions](http://www1.toronto.ca/wps/portal/contentonly?vgnextoid=ce06970aa08c1410VgnVCM10000071d60f89RCRD)

I especially like the first tip:

[image]

---

Also there are tips about riding in traffic on pages 13 through 30 of this document: [Cycling
Skills
Ontario’s Guide to
Safe Cycling](http://www.mto.gov.on.ca/english/safety/pdfs/cycling-skills.pdf)

It's all good, including the pages about trucks and buses.

Also the (Ontario-specific) law about riding on the right is interesting:

> HTA 147 - Slow moving traffic travel on right side - any vehicle moving slower than the
>   normal traffic speed should drive in the right-hand lane, or as close as practicable to the right edge of
>   the road except when preparing to turn left or when passing another vehicle. For cyclists, you must
>   **ride far enough out from the curb to maintain a straight line**, clear of sewer grates, debris, potholes,
>   and parked car doors. You may occupy any part of a lane when your safety warrants it. Never
>   compromise your safety for the convenience of a motorist behind you.

---

I general I assume that drivers are looking forward (out of their windscreen) but never assume that they're looking out their side window.

Also if I'm coming to an intersection where I have right of way (the other driver has a stop sign) then I watch for eye contact with the driver: if I have seen that they have seen me then I'm willing to cycle across their bow, otherwise (e.g. if they're looking in another direction) I might slow down, in case they pull out without having seen me, until they do look at me.

I'll try to stay out of the way (preferring roads which have an official bike lane, or a road that's wide enough for me to ride in the curb) where cars can overtake me safely.

If cars can't overtake me safely (because the road is too narrow) then I [take the lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicular_cycling) in order to prevent cars from even trying to overtake.

I also try to [ride fast enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicular_cycling#Criticism) that my doing this doesn't annoy drivers. I can't match their top speed but my acceleration (in congested city driving) is comparable. If the rate of flow of traffic on a given street is limited by the buses or [streetcars](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Tram) then I can keep up with (even overtake) them, so even when I'm in lane I'm not 'getting in the way' of drivers (because I'm keeping up with the vehicle ahead of me).

I use lights at night, and hand-signals before turning (and, sometimes, when slowing).

I keep an ear out for traffic (and I avoid, e.g. by pulling into the curb/kerb, people who are gunning their engines). Obviously I watch what's ahead but (moreso than when driving a car) I watch for what's behind and beside me.

I have excellent brakes (hydraulic disk brakes) and I'm willing to use them.

I avoid roads on which bikes are unexpected (e.g. a type of multi-lane city throughway whose top speed is 60 kph instead of the more usual 50 kph).

Comment: This goes along with riding fast enough. Try to give yourself room to accelerate.  If you are going all out, then the only thing you can do to avoid a collision is stop or turn.  If you go at a speed that allows you to accelerate, that gives you an extra way to avoid obstacles.  This doesn't only apply to speed, but also to being in the correct gear. Being in the correct gear for your speed can be important in determining whether or not you have the ability to accelerate.

Comment: Big, visible hand signals. Not just point vaguely at the ground. Hold your arm out at right angles.

Comment: I sometimes use arm signals when staying on a road/going straight ahead where most cyclists do leave the road at that point. My arm is then stretched over the handle bar, the left arm as that is the nearest to the cars in my case. (In England I would use the right one.) Specially on roundabouts I feel much better. (We have right of way on most roundabouts.)

Comment: +1 for the tip about assuming the drivers are only looking forward

Answer (score 18):

In the long term, you can also lobby and campaign for better cycling provision. The personal safety advice (better visibility etc.) is all valuable, but there is only so much you can do when a junction s poorly designed and creates conflict between different road users. Basically, if you feel unsafe on the road, then the road needs to be designed better.

Lobbying for better cycle lanes will of course not make cycling safer or more pleasant immediately, but there is a good chance you will see improvements over the years. In Edinburgh (where I live) we've seen huge steps forward, both in quantity and quality of cycle provision, thanks to very substantial and constructive campaigning by various groups, and by now almost all local councillors are publicly in favour of supporting cycling as sustainable transport that solves a lot of inner-city problems (congestion, noise, pollution, health etc.). Cycling into town feels significantly safer and more comfortable now than it did just five years ago.

In practice, you can:

- Write to your local politician and/or to the roads authorities arguing (politely) for improvements. It works best if you can be specific, e.g. explain the situation at a particular junction where you have most difficulties with other traffic.
- Road authorities often have public consultations before roadworks or road redesigns. Take part, look at the plans, go to consultation events and comment if you feel that cyclists haven't been considered enough.
- Join a local or national campaign group for better cycling provision; there are more and more popping up all over the world. They are aware of local developments and often have a lot of expertise on road design etc. Even if you don't have the time to become active yourself, just being a supporting member lends weight to their work.

Campaigning can be quite frustrating as you'll get a lot of opposition against your suggestions, but even if you don't see immediate results it will put cycling on the agenda and politicians become aware that the current situation is not good enough.

Comment: One of the better sites to get inspiration is "A view from the cycle path" by David Hembrow http://www.aviewfromthecyclepath.com/2008/09/three-types-of-safety.html here set to a rather random page.

Answer (score 13):

Be visible, be predictable (e.g. obey the rules, give hand signs, avoid sudden turns or braking) and leave a safety margin for the errors of others (e.g. don’t ride too close to parked cars).

Personally I prefer riding on roads like any other vehicle and with quite a bit of distance to the curb.

Edit: I forgot “be attentive”. E.g. Look over your shoulder when doing a left turn. I’ve been overtaken on occasion despite indicating with my fully outstretched arm.

Comment: It’s what I miss most on cycleways. People suddenly swerve to the left or jump across the path with no indication whatsoever.

Comment: "I’ve been overtaken on occasion despite indicating with my fully outstretched arm." - In the Netherlands traffic that goes straight (parallel) goes first.

Comment: @RobAu: Traffic coming towards you, yes. But I wrote “overtaken”, meaning: When I indicated and slowed down in order to turn left, a car from behind me used the chance to overtake me on my left side. Had I not looked over my shoulder I would have turned directly into the overtaking car. And yes, I indicated quite early enough.

Comment: When turning left you should be turning from the left (or middle) of the leftmost lane.  If you can't do that, it's safer to stop and cross as a pedestrian would.  Whether cars should slow down and wait for you to cross their path is at best debatable.  I believe that @RobAu is right and that traffic going straight has priority.

Comment: @gerrit: It was only one lane in each direction. No seperate lane for turning. I made this crude drawing to illustrate: http://s29.postimg.org/cuz3saokn/stackexchange.png Of course a car on the other lane (opposite direction) would have priority. But there was none, otherwise the car behind me wouldn’t have been able to overtake (without accident). If there is space (i.e. because of a seperate turning lane) and the car overtakes on the right it’s completly okay and legal. I hope this clears things up. English is not my native language and I’m not used to discussing street law.

Comment: If there is only one lane in each direction, ride on the *left* of the lane (i.e. in the middle of the road) before turning, such that cars have sufficient space to pass you on your *right* (which is where they should be passing you when you are about to turn left, so your path does not intersect with theirs).  In Dutch we call this *voorsorteren* and it's a major part of cycling education.  Literally, it means *pre-sorting*.

Comment: Yes of course. I have my driving licence and I usually obey almost all the laws. (which is why I hate it when others don’t)

Answer (score 10):

this is a question I've given a great deal of thought and experimentation to, after an accidental discovery some years ago.

Long story short: cycle where the kerb-side wheel of a car or truck would be, and magically, Jedi-mind-trickily, almost ALL drivers give you plenty of room when passing, wait patiently to pass, and are not in the slightest bit annoyed.  I know -it's like suddenly a population of saints take over all the vehicles.

I know it seems unbelievable, but please try it yourself. If you go closer to the kerb, vehicles will "buzz" you close (like you're not there at all), if you go closer to the center-line you'll get cursing and beeping (as you're in the way), but if you track where the kerb-side wheel of a travelling vehicle "naturally goes" just see what happens. I call it the Goldilocks zone.

I'd love for some University to formally test this - as I say, I did it by mistake one day (day-dreaming in a narrow lane doh!) and have experimented over many years in many different environments (city, suburb, open country) and it darn near ALWAYS works. Go figure!

Comment: This is simply part of the "claim your lane" strategy that most experienced cyclists employ.  There are times when you should swing wider, and times when you should squeeze closer to the shoulder, but mainly you stay about a third of the way out in the lane.

Answer (score 6):

Be assertive. If you need to take up a whole lane take up a whole lane, you have as many rights (in the UK at least) as cars. It will annoy drivers, but I'd rather someone shouted abuse at me as they drove past than have someone hit me because they couldn't see me.

Also stay 2-3 feet out from the pavement/sidewalk and parked cars. This will make cars slow down to get round you instead of squeezing through a small gap, and if they try to squeeze past you have enough space to dive into.

Also as everyone else says, be predictable, follow the rules, be visible and be sensible. Doesn't matter if you're in the right you are always coming second in a collision with a car.

Answer (score 5):

Get your country to invest in proper infrastructure.

When people driving and people cycling do not share the same roads, the chances on accidents are much smaller.
But the infrastructure has to be made right. Learn from the experience the Dutch gained in the last 30 years and build what we get now, not what we now know does not work the best (like those advance bike boxes at crossings.)

Maybe the best site in the world about cycling infrastructure is [A view from the cycle path](http://www.aviewfromthecyclepath.com/2013/04/the-netherlands-sets-best-example-but.html), and this link gives you the page on what to copy when building infrastructure.

> The Netherlands sets the best example, but don't copy anything just because it is "Dutch".  While Germany is a genuine leader in renewable energy, and Danish design is known across the world, it is the Netherlands that should be looked to as the leader in cycling.

Added:
I see from the downvotes that people do not like my solution, but there is proof, and plenty of it, that it is the best and only real working solution. Read the site I linked to for many more arguments and proof.
An other source of information on what works and why it works, for safe cycling, [Not Just Bikes,](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0intLFzLaudFG-xAvUEO-A) in this case with a video about [Copenhagen compared to Amsterdam.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjzzV2Akyds)
This is a channel where most of the videos are great to explain why cycling works in the Netherlands.

Comment: It's true we need better infrastructure, but the Netherlands has the benefit of far more daily riders than here in the U.S. Dutch drivers are so used to dealing with cyclists than our car-obsessed culture, but that is slowly improving.  Discouraging cycling until better infrastructure is in place only makes us less safe in the long run, IMO.

Comment: So, what could the rest of world learn from us Dutch(wo)men, who have spend years on our bikes in heavy traffic?

Comment: 45 years of building cycling infrastructure has taught the Dutch that teaching the cyclists is not enough. Even the best roads still require the cyclists to be careful, but until the roads are made safe, the best a cyclist can do is not enough to make cycling safe and enjoyable.

Comment: It's not just drivers, cyclists are trained better as well. Dutch kids all has lessons, including an on the road exam, on how to cycle through traffic. The same goes for drivers, you will fail your driving test if you don't take proper care of cyclist.

Comment: @AVee But we have learned that even the best lessons come to nothing if the roads are not safe. England spends more teaching each kid, with formal lessons, and no parent let their 12 year old cycle to school alone. In the Netherlands most kids start cycling or walking to school alone well before the cycle lessons start.

Comment: True,  nothing beats proper infrastructure, but you can't get that instantly.

Answer (score 5):

US rider so these may not apply to everyone.

First know your local laws. There are some state laws and many city or county laws. Know them and know what to expect. Some of these suggestions may not work for you in your area.

- Wear visable clothing. This usually doesn't need to include "parking cone orange" but, stay away from "urban camo" as well. Normal, non-dark clothing should do fine. Many lines of active ware come with a reflective or brightly colored stripe. Those will do just fine.
- Get a head light and tale light and use them in less sunny conditions. You don't need them, and the won't do much an a sunny summer day at noon, but as the sun starts to go down and you gen near the dusk hours they can be the best things ever for visibility. Setting your headlight to always on, and pointing it at the ground is good (in combinations with other tips here). Your tail light should be on annoying blink mode.
- Unless you have no choice, do not ride at night.
- Pretend your a car. Seriously. You are given the same rights as a car, and the same responsibilities. If you get into an accident the law will treat you as a vehicle.
- Know the area. Know where the bike lanes are, where the wide shoulders are, and where the tight fits are. Be prepared to do different things in different sections of road.
- Be predictable. Follow the laws of the road, just like you were in a car. Stop at stop signs, yield at right turns, and follow the order of "who goes next" at non-lighted intersections. Being predictable is very important.
- **STAY OFF THE SIDE WALK** You are going way to fast to have to dodge people.
- **TRAVEL WITH TRAFFIC** I have no idea why it became popular to travel against traffic, but don't, just don't. It's illegal, it's dangerous, and it's nearly impossible to see you when turning. Get to the correct side of the road.
- Don't ride next to parked cars. Just don't. Move over, away from the parking lane, far enough that if a door swings out in front of you, you can not be hit by it. This means you may have to pass up riding in the bike lane. That is ok. There is noting illegal about not using the bike lane.
- When at an intersection. Do not "pass" the first car. Sit behind the first car. It's ok to move up the 40 other stationary cars, but sit between the first car and the second. This will increase your visibility.
- When turning right, sit to the right side of the middle of the right lane. A car should not be able to go around you on either side.
- When turning left , sit to the left side of the middle of the lane. A car should not be able to go around you.
- When traveling down a road with no wide shoulder and no bike lane, ride in the middle of the right side if the right most lane. A car should have to switch lanes to go around you (or at least move into the next lane). Plus if they are too close, you have plenty of room to move.
- When traveling down a road with a bike lane. Move out of the lane (between the first and second car if you can) at stops. Make sure to honor the stop lights and again the basic idea it to make traffic have to deal with you.
- Do not travel on roads where you can't reasonably "keep up". For example if you can do 8 MPH then stay to residential roads where the speed limit is around 25 MPH. Don't do 8 MPH in the middle of a 60 MPH road. If you can to 20 MPH then road marked as 45 MPH are probably ok. The general idea is that traffic should be able to flow around you without backing up entire spans of traffic.
- Finally, disregard every one of these rules where your safety is in concern. For example, it may be better to go one block, up a sidewalk, the wrong way, then to try to make an awkward left turn.

Answer (score 5):

Most important to always keep your head on a swivel. Look out for:

- cars, which could be turning from a side road or parking lot or coming up fast behind you (making a lane change unsafe)
- Pedestrians which may not look on the road when crossing and are not on the road initially.
- Parked cars, which could open there door at any moment. Assume this will happen to all parked cars. Ride outside the door zone even if it means not riding on the far right of the road.
- Hazard in the road including pot holes, debris, puddles, etc.
  Threats can come from anywhere at any time on or off the road. When I am riding my bike in the city I am about as focused as I ever am, constantly scanning for things that may injure me.

Other tips:

**Don't be afraid to ride in the middle of the lane** when necessary. Make a car acknowledge your spot on the road an pass you. As you ride more you will learn situations when you should take the lane. Any time it would be unsafe for a car to pass you or you may not be seen you should ride in the middle of the lane. A few specific examples:

- At traffic lights, take your spot in line behind a car.
- If there are hazards on the side of the road like debris or parked car (maybe not ride in the middle but dont ride on the edge of the lane).
- If you need to turn left soon, signal early and obviously, then take the lane as you switch to the left turn lane. You can't go from the far right to the left very quickly or safely otherwise

**Signal obviously**

this is important to show your intentions to a driver. As you become more confident you can signal and make drivers obey you as you perform more aggressive maneuvers

**Be good at riding your bike**

If you can't confidently maneuver in traffic then don't ride in traffic. To try and specify useful skills:

- You need to be able to ride straight while you look over your shoulder
- Being able to pedal faster will be safer in traffic. You are less of an obstruction if you can nearly keep up with traffic
- you should be confident to make a quick turn to avoid a collision

Additionally you should have good brakes so you can stop if you suddenly need to. In fact, a well maintained bicycle is very important for your safety. If your tires are dry rotted, maybe they will burst while you are riding. If the chain breaks while you are pedaling hard you could fall. If your bike is too small for you, you could become off balanced while pedaling and fall (this happened to me once and it was a nasty wipeout). Large pedals can also be helpful for keeping your grip.

And of course, wear a helmet, but hopefully these tips help you not fall in the first place

Answer (score 4):

Most of the advice you're getting here is great, but a few caveats:

- When hand-signaling, wave your hand a little, or even raise and lower your arm a couple times. I believe it triggers an instinctive response in people who see that in their peripheral vision ("Ooh! Who's that waving at me? Do I know this person?"), and they notice me far more often.
- As cars are approaching, and are still well behind you, turn your head to look back.  Again, I believe it triggers that same instinctive response.
- If you live in a region where riding with blinking lights is illegal, encourage every local cycling group to lobby for a change to that law.  It's stupid, and only creates a higher risk of collision.
- Obviously don't ride at night with blinking headlights, but always use a blinking taillight. But in the daytime, if allowed, do it 100% of the time.
- Get bright lights! Most cheaper lights just don't attract enough attention.
- When using a bike lane, hug the line until vehicles are near you, then fade toward the curb as they're passing (if you won't get doored), just as you would do on roads without bike lanes.
- Get some hi-vis stickers and apply them to different areas of your bike.  Under vehicle headlights, they're as visible as bike lights.
- When taking the lane, ride in front of the driver's position to increase your odds of being seen.

I've followed these guidelines for the past six years without incident, on an asphalt-grey bike with black fenders, and without wearing any bright clothing (not that brighter clothing is unnecessary - just not my style).

Comment: "...hug the outside edge ..., then fade toward the edge". Er... so, the former "edge" is apparently "outside edge". What is the latter "edge" then?  What is the difference between "outside edge" and "edge"?

Comment: +1 for the lights advice. Although I disagree with the waving advice. If we all did it, we'd look like a flock of seagulls! It would be very confusing :-)

Comment: @andy256 If I lived in an area with a lot more cyclists, I'd probably do that less by nature, since drivers would be more used to us.  I'm one of a few I see daily on my commute.  I'm talking about a brief wave, not a full-on "hello" wave.

Comment: @digijim Don't wave your arm up and down when performing a turn signal - this could be confused with the "I'm stopping" signal (in the UK at least) and will only encourage drivers to try and overtake just as you are about to make your turn.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking as a driver, what you can do:

1. Be visible.  During the day, this means bright-colored clothing.  At night, lights and broad retro-reflector stripes.  Urban camouflage may be fashionable, but it's also a good way to keep drivers from seeing you.
2. Be predictable.  Because you are one of the slowest vehicles on the road, everyone else is reacting to you.  Make it easy for them: stay in the same lane and the same *part* of the lane as much as possible, and signal your maneuvers well in advance.
3. Follow the law.  This goes hand-in-hand with being predictable: those stop signs, red lights, and direction-of-travel laws apply to you just as much to a car.
4. If you can't go a respectable fraction of the speed limit, stay off the road.  Most cars have a minimum practical speed (typically around 15 km/h - 10 mph), and if someone is constantly tapping their brakes to keep from rear-ending you, that's not a safe situation.

Comment: "If you can't go a respectable fraction of the speed limit, stay off the road." Not always an option. In many jurisdictions, cycling on the footway is illegal and, in many places, there's only one road it's reasonable to use to get from A to B. Having said that, in most urban areas, narrow roads where it's hard for cars to pass a cyclist tend to have low speed limits, too. Also, if you do have a line of cars behind you, pull over to let them pass if that can be done reasonably.

Comment: I have to agree with point 4.  But that you should qualify what a respectable fraction of the speed is.  Going 15 km/h on a 60 km/h road is probably fine. That's a 1:4 ratio.  However, I wouldn't rate the same as going 25 km/h on a 100 km/h road, even though it's the same ratio.  [Stopping distance does not increase linearly with speed](http://www.sdt.com.au/safedrive-directory-STOPPINGDISTANCE.htm).  Try to stay off high speed roads unless they have specific provisions for cyclists such as a large shoulder.

Comment: I find 4. downright offensive: There are roads many cyclists use that are well above 10% inclination - Part of my commute is [Zürich Gsteigstrasse](http://osm.org/go/0C0UzvVSh-?way=4626793) climbing 60m on 600m of road. I have to max out to stay above 12km/h, I've met someone there with child in trailer - it's very possible to have cyclists there doing their best to keep 5km/h. Avoiding that kind of inclination can mean multi-km detour.

Comment: @chichak, I'm sure you find it offensive.  The fact remains that a situation where someone has to take active measures to avoid a collision is more dangerous than one where no active measures are needed.

Comment: @Mark, I should clarify I think 4. is not in general a good rule at least in your wording: In the particular example of steep roads, motor vehicle drivers don't have the problem that they have to break to keep distance to cyclists. Also, most drivers pay more attention when driving steep roads. I don't feel cars are a threat to cyclists' safety in these situations, at least here in Switzerland, were people are used to steep roads. These situations might just not occur where you live.

Comment: "Most cars have a minimum practical speed (typically around 15 km/h - 10 mph)"  That makes no sense.  It's not like cars are two-wheeled vehicles that will tip over at low speeds.  My car can do anything under 70mph just fine, including 0mph.  And judging from the existence of 5mph speed limits, so can everyone else's car.

Comment: @Edward, a car *can* go at any speed, but low speeds are more difficult -- gasoline engines will stall if they're not spinning fast enough.  In cars with an automatic transmission, an idling engine will drive the car forward at 5-15 mph on a level paved road, requiring constant braking to avoid hitting something going slower.

Answer (score 3):

Visible clothing has been mentioned a couple times before. I'd like to add one suggestion within that theme: you can even wear fluorescent yellow or orange clothing, like this one I found on Google's image search:

[image]

It's light weight, practicial, dirt cheap and very visible. Especially in dawn or dusk, they seem to emit light themselves. And they are ugly. :D

Comment: That reminds me of [this road safety advertisement](http://www.champagne-ardenne.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/le-1er-octobre-c-est-jaune-c-est-moche-ca-ne-va-a515.html) in which Karl Lagerfeld says, "It's yellow, it's ugly, it doesn't go with anything, but it can save your life".

Comment: The cheap ones for keeping in your car are loose and flap around. For my motorbike I found one which is stretchy and fastens with a zip, so it's snug and stays put.

Comment: In Portugal, for car drivers it is mandatory to have a green gilet like that in the car. And to dress it in the case of an accident.

Comment: If you use normal clothing in normal bright colors you are as visible in daylight. Those plastic vests do not give more safety, they give a false sense of safety. A bright blue/white/yellow normal jacket or top is more visible and stands out better in traffic.

Answer (score 3):

Eyes - look straight at the driver and hold the gaze until they see you.   Human brains are wired to detect and pick out eyes/eyeballs in the visual field.

Try it - as a cyclist you can see clearly when the driver/other cyclist notices you.

And if they still don't see you, it gives a split second more warning to react appropriately before they pull out.... enough time for a flash glance behind, or to prepare yourself for impact.

Comment: This works *most* of the time, until you encounter a driver who has vagued out. They'll look you in the eyes and drive right through you.

Comment: Yes - and as a cyclist you see this and recognise it immediately, and then you can expect them to act like you're not there.

Good road users are predictable.  Accidents often happen when people act unpredictably.

Comment: It's not so much seeing the eyes as it is _communicating_. Key to this is signalling your intentions. But you often can't see a driver's eyes—especially through tinted windows while you're looking over your shoulder—so how do you know if _they_ have seen _you_? Wait for them to react. Sometimes it's obvious (they blip their horn to tell you to go), but other times it's subtle (they take their foot off the gas and slow down just a tiny bit). After a while you will learn to recognize these subtle forms of communication, just as you would as a pedestrian while stepping out onto a zebra crossing.

Answer (score 2):

Another tip for extra visibility - have a flag attached to your bike such as one of the kind that are normally used with bike trailers. Having something flapping about makes you more noticeable, especially from behind.

Here is an example of one that I customised, replaced the little triangle that came with it with something a bit bigger for the purpose of advertising my charity ride. It didn't result in any noticeable surge in donations but I had at least one driver telling me that they liked it not because of what I painted on it but because I could be seen more easily.

[image]

Comment: +1 for having Thing T. Thing from the Addams Family to help hold the flag :))

Comment: That driver brings up a good point, those standard flags are mostly useless, can not be seen from the normal position behind the bike, they become a small stripe. Better not have a flag and know you can not be seen. (And yes, I ride a low recumbent bike/trike, I used to have a flag and now go without.)

Answer (score 1):

Wear a full Batman suit with a night reflective cape. The Batman suit should offer good visibility for the person wearing the suit, will have a cool cape that flaps in the wind, and has places to put all those gadgets so you don't have to have them in your ears and eyes. I don't bicycle on the road anymore but as a driver you can bet I'll be staring down both the rider and the bicycle as I drive by if I see Batman.

Any of the ideas in this thread that increase the chances of eye contact will help you as it is harder to ignore somebody who has made eye contact. - So if Batman is not your style, perhaps giant cookie monster eyes on the back of your helmet will work for you.

Comment: Visible and fun helps to keep people from wanting to run you down just because you're on their part of the road.

Comment: The problem with a Batman outfit is that it will attract unwanted attention from jokers.

Comment: As the Batman, I'm going to have to disagree with this advice.

Comment: Creative ways of being noticed while on a crowded street are not for this crowd. Perhaps I didn't read the question right? - Crazy outfit gets noticed, check. People are afraid to get too close, check. - I guessing that No one knows what its like to be the Batman.

Comment: The cape is essential to the outfit. No "caped crusader" without the cape! But how do you keep the cape from tangling with the rear wheel? And wind resistance?

Comment: Excellent point. City traffic, wind resistance is going to be low. To avoid tangling, you just have to wear it slightly higher or have a shorter cape. A cape slightly shorter than an Adam West Batman would be safe for the gears.

Answer (score 1):

I am glad this thread is almost 2 years old...maybe I will not get so many downvotes because I am going to say what no one else said, what no one else dared to say. I walked, biked and driven in a couple of the great cities of the US. I am going to name names too. I think this needed to be said and I know some people are going to say they bike there all the time...

These two places are typical but stand out in my mind:

NYC - here is a city I was not safe crossing the street in. Drivers deliberately aimed for me many times and my car experienced many hit and runs where I had to drive after the perpetrator to get his license plate. This was a place where parking a bike for more than a couple of hours meant losing your bike to thieves regardless of how many U locks you had on it. I mean, if you can not walk there, drive there, park there, how can you bike there safely?

Las Vegas - here is a city where twice drivers pulled onto the sidewalk to try and get me, one continued to follow me down the sidewalk. I had 3 bikes stolen there and one time was mugged while riding in front of a famous hotel when they hit me with pipe as they passed in their car. My Mother was hit while she was crossing the street and he never stopped. A case happened in my neighborhood, kid was on his bike, got run over, guy did not stop, went home and ate a big dinner while that kid died.

If a guy would eat dinner after running over a child and say pass the gravy, is it safe to bike there in traffic? Let us face it, many motorists really hate pedestrians and cyclists. Motorists act like vicious psychopaths. It is nothing more than bullying, they weigh 3000 pounds plus and you weigh 200 or 250. They are driving out their right now, never been caught and they never will be. I have been biking for 60 years on and off and have never seen any change in their attitude.

I solved the problem by not cycling in places like the above. I moved to a small town where now when I cycle down a road I am the only thing on it. I ride the sidewalks and streets in peace. People park their bikes and run into a store and do not even lock their bike up! I put a 10 dollar chain on mine. As Mel Brooks said,"location, location, location."

Conclusion: There ain't no way to ride in the crowded cities in my United States and be safe from motorists. You take your chances...

Some will say this does not answer the question of increasing visibility. I say they see us just fine, they do not care.

Comment: Big cities can become safe for cycling, if enough of the right infrastructure is build. And that takes a change of thinking I dare not predict most countries.